# Is the set of all functions differentiable at two point meagre on the set of all functions differentiable at one point?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $D$ be the set of all continuous functions $(f)$ that is differentiable at at least one point: $D=\{f\in\mathcal C(\mathbb R):\exists p \ s.t. f'(p)\in\mathbb R\}$

Let $E$ be the set of all continuous functions $(g)$ that is differentiable at at least two point: $E=\{g\in\mathcal C(\mathbb R):\exists p_1,p_2 \ s.t. \forall i\in\{1,2\}, f'(p_i)\in\mathbb R\}$

Is $E$ meagre on $D$?

Let $C^1$ be the set of all differentiable functions. Let $L$ be the set of all almost everywhere differentiable functions. Is $C^1$ meagre on $L$?

---

I don't know how to get started. For the first question, I guess we could start by considering a subset, say $S$, of the domain. We require that $f$ is not differentiable and $g$ is differentiable at at least one point in $S$. This can always be done if the domain is $\mathbb R^n$.  Then, at least restricted in $S$, $E$ might be a meagre set in $D$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Edited. Any further suggestions are truly welcome.